# What do I, as a programmer, need to know about Behavior Driven Development?

Tags: unit-testing, bdd

To put this in context. I like TDD. I like writing my tests first, and expressing what I need my code to do using assertEquals and assertTrue etc.

But everyone seems to be getting with the BDD programme. I see a lot of talk about rSpec and Cucumber and Lettuce. When I look at these, they look overly verbose, almost like Cobol in their naive assumption that somehow writing long "pseudo-English" makes formal specifications legible to the layman.

Some of the writings about BDD make it sound like it's for people who found TDD too hard to do in practice. I don't feel I have this problem. Or, at least, where I have it's been due to problems with doing TDD against databases or in interactive environments, not because I couldn't formulate or prioritise my tests.

So my question is this. What value is BDD for me as a programmer? a) In the context of projects I'm writing for myself (or with other programmers). b) In the context of working with non-technical customers.

For people who've used BDD for a number of projects, what did it buy you over and above TDD?
Are you finding a customers, product or project managers who can write sufficiently rigid test cases in BDD but couldn't write them as ordinary tests?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested BDD on a very simple internal project, then exported it on a complex one.

I found that the main difference is the kind of test you run in BDD.
The BDD outer tests are based on acceptance tests, which do not deals with the classes or any internal code, but relay on testing the system as a whole.
The BDD inner tests are exactly the same unit test you do in TDD.

In this way you can run the same red-green-refactor approach on two levels.

I found external tests extremely helpfull on complex project.

Answer (score 0):

To answer question (a), if you don't have any non-technical stakeholders, then maybe Cucumber isn't appropriate, but are you confident you have sufficient integration testing in place? Unit tests usually aren't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I like this video's discussion on the difference between TDD and BDD: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Brandom-Satrom-BDD-in-ASPNET-MVC-using-SpecFlow-WatiN-and-WatiN-Test-Helpers  (its .NET tools, and not necessarily the .NET tools I use, but the concepts are right)

Generally, you might say it improves your feedback loop by changing it to check if you think the software is implemented as you'd expect (with TDD) to check if the software meets requirements from your users' perspectives (with BDD).